# How to call Fragment method from activity to update listview in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to update listview in fragment from main activity after selecting item from dialog.

I am using FragmentPagerAdapter in this Activity

My Dialog method

```
private void showDialog(String routeName) {

        MyTTCDB db = new MyTTCDB(this);
        List<String> directions = db.getDirectionByRoute(routeName);

        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builderSingle.setTitle("Direction");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);

        for (String string : directions) {
            arrayAdapter.add(string);
        }

        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        String side = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);

                        FragmentStops fragment = (FragmentStops) mSectionsPagerAdapter
                                .getItem(1);
                        fragment.refresh(side);

                    }
                });
        builderSingle.show();

    }
```

My Fragment

```
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.anilvasani.myttc.StopsActivity.Interface_FragmentStops;
import com.anilvasani.myttc.adapter.AdapterStops;
import com.anilvasani.myttc.data.MyTTCDB;
import com.anilvasani.myttc.models.Stop;

public class FragmentStops extends Fragment {

    View view;
    AdapterStops myAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragement_stops, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    public void refresh(String side) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String routeName = getActivity().getIntent()
                .getStringExtra("routeName").toString();

        ListView listStops = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_listView);
        // EditText txtSearch=(EditText)
        // view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_txtSearch);

        MyTTCDB db = new MyTTCDB(getActivity());
        List<Stop> allStops = db.getAllStopsByRouteAndSide(routeName, side);
        myAdapter = new AdapterStops(getActivity(), allStops);
        listStops.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

}
```

I am getting errors like...

```
12-14 23:43:02.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7577): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 23:43:02.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7577):   at com.anilvasani.myttc.FragmentStops.refresh(FragmentStops.java:34)
12-14 23:43:02.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7577):   at com.anilvasani.myttc.StopsActivity$3.onClick(StopsActivity.java:120)
12-14 23:43:02.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7577):   at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
```

So please help me, How to call method of Fragment from Activity based on user's input.

Comment: what is line 34 `FragmetnStops.java`?

Comment: It looks like you're successfully calling refresh() in StopFragment from your DialogFragment, but you're receiving a NullPointerError at line 34 in your StopsFragment class. Check your variables at line 34 and see what is null.

Comment: I think you can use listeners .

Answer (score 0):

It seems your error is coming from the line:

`String routeName = getActivity().getIntent()
                .getStringExtra("routeName").toString();`

Make sure of the following things:

- That when you started the activity that you calling refresh method (the activity that the dialog is attached to) that you start the activity in an intent since `getIntent()` is trying to return that intent.
- Next make sure that there is a String named "routeName" and that that String is not null.

I hope this helps